# Was genau ist der Unterschied zwischen "in einer Achse" und "auf einer Achse"?

Tags: difference, preposition, meaning-in-context

Hallo erst mal an alle,

meine Kollegin und ich versuchen gerade den Unterschied zwischen den Phrasen **in einer Achse angeordnet** und **auf einer Achse angeordnet** herauszufinden. Die gängige Google-Suche hat leider nichts Brauchbares ergeben. Wir sind uns auch nicht ganz sicher, ob das mal wieder eine der vielen Patentformulierungen ist, die die Regeln des normalen Sprachgebrauchs nicht immer beachten (Mehr Kontext oder Beispiele kann ich leider nicht liefern, da es sich hier wie erwähnt um Patente handelt und ich zur Verschwiegenheit verplichtet bin).

Comment: Spontan würde ich sagen, dass es auf die Blickrichtung ankommt. "In einer Achse" angeordnet impliziert für mich, dass man quasi die Achse entlangpeilt. "Auf einer Achse" angeordnet hat diese Implikation nicht, der Betrachtet schaut von irgendwo auf das System.

Comment: lol. Können wir hier einen Patentstreit schlichten :-) ? Ich habe aber noch Einen: "Um eine Achse ...". Vielleicht kann (je nach Kontext, ohne den wir auch nur heftig raten können) die Lage der Achse relativ zum Betrachter und den Gegenständen, auf die sich die Achse bezieht, Klarheit schaffen. Wenn's da keine Unterschiede gibt, dann sind die Begriffe im gegebenen Fall identisch. Für diese Angaben keine Gewähr :-)

Comment: Kein Patentstreit, es geht um die Übersetzung des Patents und da soll natürlich möglichst richtig übersetzt werden. "Um eine Achse" wäre also relativ einfach zu übersetzen, sofern es richtig verwendet wird (was leider das größte Problem ist). Der Hinweis mit der Blickrichtung ist ganz gut, sollte die untenstehende Antwort mal nicht greifen. Auf jeden Fall freuen wir uns, dass wir nun ein paar Anhaltspunkte haben. :)

Answer (score 4):

> in einer Achse angeordnet

Heißt für mich, dass alle Dinge entlang einer virtuellen Achse/Linie angeordnet sind. Sie sind damit im weiteren Sinn nacheinander angeordnet - `der Mond ist in einer Achse mit der Erde angeordnet`. Es kann aber auch heißen, es gibt eine physische Achse und da innen drin sind die angeordneten Objekte.

> auf einer Achse angeordnet

Heißt für mich primär, dass es eine Achse/Welle gibt, auf der die Dinge draufmontiert sind - `Die Pleuelstangen sind auf der Kurbelwelle angeordnet`. Allerdings kenne ich auch die Verkürzung als "auf einer gedachten Achse angeordnet" - was dann so verwendet wird wie "in einer Achse"

> entlang einer Achse angeordnet

Wäre nun der Fall, der beides meinen kann.

Die größte Schwierigkeit hier ist: Welche Sorgfalt & Bedeutung ist beim Verfassen angewendet worden?

Daher muss der weitere Kontext ergeben, ob es überhaupt sein kann, dass die physische Achse fehlt oder ob es nur als relative Lagebeschreibung zu verstehen ist.

Comment: Dann lagen wir ja gar nicht so daneben mit unseren laienhaften Erklärungsvorschlägen! Ja, die Sache mit der Sorgfalt und Bedeutung ist heiß diskutiert unter uns Übersetzern, aber wenn es jemanden gibt, der das ähnlich erklärt und sieht, dann ist uns schon viel geholfen. Vielen Dank!